# Concat Two Command Result in File

Tags: file, unix, output, concatenation

I have two commands:

```
cat BIG_DATAfinal.txt | grep "STATUS" | awk '{print $5}' 
cat BIG_DATAfinal.txt | grep "start" | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/time;//g'
```

I want concat this two command in a file.

example:

> STATUS REPORT FOR JOB: CargaDestino
>   Generated: 2016-06-17 10:52:14
>      Job start time;2015-03-30 13:11:45
>      Job end time;2016-06-17 10:52:14
>      Job elapsed time;10677:40:29
>      Job status;99 (Not running)

The expected result would be:

> CargaDestino;2015-03-30

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
a=`cat BIG_DATAfinal.txt | grep "STATUS" | awk '{print $5}'`
b=`cat BIG_DATAfinal.txt | grep "start" | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/time;//g'`
echo "$a;$b"
```

Comment: Yes, but i tried this command: echo "$a;$b" and the result gave me this: ;2015-03-30argaDestino

Comment: new line problem, use printf... or put the results into 2 different files and use `join`

Comment: I have problems whit my MKS version. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single awk program:

```
awk -v OFS=";" '
    /STATUS/ {status=$5} 
    /start/ {split($3, a, /;/); start=a[2]} 
    status && start {print status, start; status=start=""}
' BIG_DATAfinal.txt
```

If the output looks like `;2015-03-30o`, then your file has `\r\n` line endings, and you should do this:

```
sed 's/\r$//' BIG_DATAfinal.txt | awk -v OFS=";" '
    /STATUS/ {status=$5} 
    /start/ {split($3, a, /;/); start=a[2]} 
    status && start {print status, start; status=start=""}
'
```